# How to make image distributed to screen width in RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have three icon the a `RelativeLayout`, how to make them distributed to screen width?

Since I may add more icon to this line programmatically, I cannot hard code a fixed margin to these icon.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/icon1"
        android:src="@mipmap/icon" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/icon2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/icon1"
        android:src="@mipmap/icon" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/icon3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/icon2"
        android:src="@mipmap/icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use `LinearLayout`
and use this code, which will work in all resolutions device.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/icon1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/icon2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code with small modification in attributes.

Try this:

```
 <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/icon1"
        android:src="@mipmap/icon" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/icon2"
        android:layout_below="@id/icon1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="@id/icon1"
        android:src="@mipmap/icon" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/icon3"
        android:layout_below="@id/icon2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="@id/icon2"
        android:src="@mipmap/icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```